# Ethereum Validators - Can IPFS/Arweave/etc. Host Rocket Pool's Minipool?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ipfs, validators

**Is it possible to host a Rocket Pool [Minipool](http://docs.rocketpool.net/guides/node/create-validator.html) Ethereum validator on [IPFS](https://ipfs.io), [Arweave](https://www.arweave.org/), or etc.?**

The IPFS/Arweave data would be encrypted to not expose the ETH Validator's private key.

IPFS and Arweave are built for storing content data such as websites, assets, photos/videos, etc. rather than hosting or running code. However, are there potential workarounds to host code on IPFS/Arweave or any "IPFS/Arweave for server" solutions that are comparably decentralized?

Answer (score 1):

No, IPFS/Arweave/etc are the **storage layers**. They can just host your static files, even the code base, but for the execution layer, you must have some machine running, at home/in the cloud - to fetch the code and keep it running.

Comment: Are there any equivalently decentralized execution layers for running code/apps?